# Read properties from common config in frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I have a Django server in the backend and React server in the front end.
for example, I have this function in the backend:

```
def create(request):
    fname = request.data['first_name']
    lname = request.data['last_name']
```

and this is my front:

```
function() {
    axios.post({first_name:x, last_name:y}, url, headers)
}
```

I need to read first_name from a common config that is shared with the front and back.
in other words, if I want to change first_name to firstname, I only need to change common config(not frontend or backend codes)